# Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.CryptographicEngine.Encrypt() throwing InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, cryptography, uwp, hololens

I'm porting some crypto code to UWP for HoloLens. AFAIK, I've implemented it perfectly according to UWP requirements, but I get a mysterious InvalidCastException from the following code:

```
public override byte[] Encrypt(byte[] clearData, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
```

```
IBuffer dataBuffer = WindowsRuntimeBuffer.Create(clearData, 0, clearData.Length, clearData.Length);
IBuffer keyBuffer = WindowsRuntimeBuffer.Create(Key, 0, Key.Length, Key.Length);
IBuffer ivBuffer = WindowsRuntimeBuffer.Create(IV, 0, IV.Length, IV.Length);

string strAlgName = KeyDerivationAlgorithmNames.Pbkdf2Sha256;

// Open the specified algorithm.
KeyDerivationAlgorithmProvider objAlgProv = KeyDerivationAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(strAlgName);

// Create a key by using the passed buffer.
CryptographicKey key = objAlgProv.CreateKey(keyBuffer);

IBuffer encryptedData = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(key, dataBuffer, ivBuffer); // throws System.InvalidCastException
return (byte[])encryptedData.ToArray();
```

I'm not really sure what the issue is. I've verified that the types of all parameters being passed into CryptographicEngine.Encrypt are the right type. I tried the AsBuffer extension method earlier on my byte arrays; I switched to WindowsRuntimeBuffer.Create thinking that might do the trick, but it makes no difference whatsoever. dataBuffer and ivBuffer are both of type WindowsRuntimeBuffer, which implements IBuffer, and both are a length that is a multiple of 8 (32 and 16, respectively). I tried casting as IBuffer; that didn't work. I even tried generating 3 random IBuffers, all of lenght 32, to see if that would at least work; it doesn't work. Is this a bug, or am I missing something really obvious? Moreover, the InvalidCastException is completely generic and only gives me the StackTrace from my own app, which tells me absolutely nothing.

FWIW, here's the whole stack trace:

```
   at Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(CryptographicKey key, IBuffer data, IBuffer iv)
   at dk.UWP.Crypto.UWPSimpleEncryption.Encrypt(Byte[] clearData, Byte[] Key, Byte[] IV)
   at dk.UWP.Crypto.UWPSimpleEncryption.Encrypt(String clearText, String Password)
   at dk.Crypto.SimpleEncryption.Encrypt(String clearText, String Password)
   at bbtb.Scene.BBTBInitialization.<DeferSplashForInitialization>d__19.MoveNext()
   at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator enumerator, IntPtr returnValueAddress)
   at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.$Invoke1InvokeMoveNext(Int64 instance, Int64* args)
   at UnityEngine.Internal.$MethodUtility.InvokeMethod(Int64 instance, Int64* args, IntPtr method)
```

Comment: You're trying to encrypt something with a PBKDF2 "key", which is not something that exists. What exactly is the code supposed to do? Can you show us the existing code that you port it from?

Comment: @ArtjomB., the code above is based on the boilerplate code from the MSDN samples:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.cryptographicengine

...it's my understanding from the documentation that the key isn't PBKDF2, but rather the algorithm. The key is then generated from the algortihm using the buffer provided. If I'm incorrect about this, please let me know. Should I be using a different algorithm? They don't provide much info on MSDN about the differences between them, and I'm not sure how this would cause an InvalidCastException.

Comment: Here's the old code, but understand that the old code isn't relevant whatsoever to the question I asked, as it is completely unsupported on UWP/Holographic:


`MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); 

Rijndael alg = Rijndael.Create(); 
alg.Key = Key; 
alg.IV = IV; 

CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, alg.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write); 
cs.Write(clearData, 0, clearData.Length); 
cs.Close(); 

byte[] encryptedData = ms.ToArray();
   
return encryptedData;`

Comment: `IBuffer dataBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(1);
string strAlgName = KeyDerivationAlgorithmNames.Pbkdf2Sha256;
KeyDerivationAlgorithmProvider objKdfProv = KeyDerivationAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(strAlgName);
IBuffer secret = CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(32);
CryptographicKey key = objKdfProv.CreateKey(secret);
      
CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(key, dataBuffer, null); // Still throws System.InvalidCastException`

Comment: The above is a maximally reduced case of encryption; still doesn't work.

Comment: I've submitted the following bug to MS:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3106919

Comment: PBKDF2 is a key-derivation algorithm. It's **not** an encryption algorithm. If you want to encrypt using AES (Rijndael is a superset of AES), you should use PBKDF2 as a key-derviation function to get a key and subsequently use that to encrypt something. It's not a bug, because you haven't specified the cipher. Look at the example in the documentation for the first part: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.keyderivationalgorithmprovider.aspx

Comment: @ArtjomB., the MSDN documentation is where I derived this code in the first place. Look at the code again; I'm doing exactly as you say already. I'm using PBKDF2 to derive a key, not for the final encryption.

Comment: I've looked at your code. You're using `CryptographicEngine.Encrypt` with a PBKDF2 "key". Since PBKDF2 is not an encryption algorithm on its own, this will obviously not work.

Comment: Yup, thanks for your help @ArtjomB.; I didn't understand what you were saying. See my answer below. The full answer is a little more intricate in terms of functional code; but you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if, for whatever reason, the examples MSDN provides with KeyDerivationAlgorithmProvider and KeyDerivationAlgorithmNames do not work. If you instead use SymmetricAlgorithmNames and SymmetricAlgorithmProvider, it seems to work fine. I'm not sure if this is by design; if so, it is completely undocumented. I will post more information if I discover it.

Comment: If the examples are wrong, do you have some example code?

Comment: This issue from 2012 fully explains and resolves the issue:
http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/MVC/Post/Thread/85b1b57a-3b4b-420a-b01f-154cdaa68cbc?category=winappswithcsharp

Comment: Although it is not clearly documented, different algorithm providers are used for key derivation and encryption. Similar to what you were saying earlier, @ArtjomB., the difference being that I was deriving the key correctly, but passing that key to Encrypt() is wrong. You need two keys - one to generate an iv buffer for encryption - and another, symmetric key for encryption as well. The key buffer from the first key also gets fed into the creation process for the symmetric key. The examples on the page for CryptographicEngine are unfortunately generic and don't capture these details well.